# How to select this via jQuery (include text in selector)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What is a safe and reliable way to select the link below? I am having trouble to ensure I include the "Select" text in the selector to ensure I do not select another link:

```
<span class="pickerWrapper">....<a href="...">Select</a></span>
```

Comment: that depends on whats in .... after span. Are there more anchor tags. Please specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.class a:contains("Select"):last')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WwSNb/

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use the **[contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**.

```
$(".pickerWrapper a:contains('Select')");
```

Comment: How do I get the last link that contains 'Select' though? Doesn't contain return a collection of elements?

Comment: This will return all links that contain the text "Select".  If you want to always return one, you could use :first, :last, or other combinations of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(".pickerWrapper a:last")  should work

Comment: How do I ensure that the last link contains 'Select'? Is there a way to include this in your selector?